# Passing 8192 sockets via systemd socket activation - fails with E2BIG

Tags: systemd, socket, max-file-descriptors

I am trying to have systemd start up a daemon and pass it 8,192 listening sockets.  I have a `.service` and `.socket` file that work reliably with a more "normal" number of listening sockets, like this:

```
# a-daemon.socket
[Unit]
Description=A Daemon (sockets)
After=network.target

[Socket]
Accept=no
ListenStream=8192

# a-daemon.service
[Unit]
Description=A Daemon
After=network.target
Requires=a-daemon.socket

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/a-daemon
```

But if I swap out `a-daemon.socket` for a version with 8,192 `ListenStream` lines, one for each TCP port from 8192 through 16383 inclusive, then the daemon won't start any more.  The *socket* unit can be started just fine, but the *service* unit fails; the only error message I get is

```
systemd[17563]: a-daemon.service: Failed to execute command: Argument list too long
systemd[17563]: a-daemon.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/sbin/a-daemon: Argument list too long
```

As I understand it, this can't actually be a problem with the *argument list*, because systemd doesn't put the socket fd numbers on the daemon's command line or anything like that.  I guessed it was instead a problem with a limit on the number of simultaneous open files, so I set `DefaultLimitNOFILE=32768` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and an equivalent setting in `/etc/security/limits.conf` and rebooted.  No change.  Then I put `ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/prlimit -n` in the .service file and tried to restart it, which confirmed that the increased limit *had* taken effect:

```
prlimit[18134]: RESOURCE   DESCRIPTION                             SOFT      HARD UNITS
prlimit[18134]: NOFILE     max number of open files               32768     32768 files
```

But the service still fails, the same way.  And now I'm out of ideas.  Can you suggest anything I could try doing to make this work?

(I am aware that listening on 8,192 consecutive TCP ports is a weird thing to do.  Please take my word for it that I have a good reason which I cannot share.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon staring at the systemd manpages some more, I realized that there *is* something systemd puts in the `argv` area whose size is proportional to the number of listening sockets:

> `sd_listen_fds_with_names()` is like `sd_listen_fds()`, but optionally also
> returns an array of strings with identification names for the passed
> file descriptors, if that is available and the names parameter is
> non-NULL. **This information is read from the `$LISTEN_FDNAMES` [environment] variable,
> which may contain a colon-separated list of names.** For socket-activated
> services, these names may be configured with the `FileDescriptorName=`
> setting in socket unit files, see `systemd.socket(5)` for details.

(boldface - my emphasis)  What this means is, if you have 8192 `ListenStream` entries in a socket unit file, systemd will try to put `LISTEN_FDNAMES=[name]:[name]:...`, with 8192 repeats, where `name` is the `FileDescriptorName` setting, into the environment for the service. `FileDescriptorName` defaults to the full basename of the socket unit file.  This can easily overflow Linux's fairly low, fixed limit on the length of a single environment variable name+value (`MAX_ARG_STRLEN`, usually 128k), and thus cause `execve(2)` to fail with `E2BIG`.

For a daemon that doesn't care about the names, the cure is to put

```
UnsetEnvironment=LISTEN_FDNAMES
```

in the *service* file (`[Service]` section).  This eliminates the problem environment variable and makes the kernel happy.

I don't know what you do if you actually *need* the fd names for something and you hit this limit.